# Best implementation of Java Queue?

Tags: java, queue

I am working (in Java) on a recursive image processing algorithm that recursively traverses the pixels of the image, outwards from a center point.

Unfortunately, that causes a Stack Overflow. So I have decided to switch to a Queue-based algorithm.

Now, this is all fine and dandy- but considering the fact that its queue will be analyzing THOUSANDS of pixels in a very short amount of time, while constantly popping and pushing, WITHOUT maintaining a predictable state (It could be anywhere between length 100, and 20000), the queue implementation needs to have significantly fast popping and pushing abilities.

A linked list seems attractive due to its ability to push elements onto itself without rearranging anything else in the list, but in order for it to be fast enough, it would need easy access to both its head, AND its tail (or second-to-last node if it were not doubly-linked). Sadly, I cannot find any information related to the underlying implementation of linked lists in Java, so it's hard to say if a linked list is really the way to go...

This brings me to my question. What would be the best implementation of the Queue interface in Java for what I intend to do? (I do not wish to edit or even access anything other than the head and tail of the queue -- I do not wish to do any sort of rearranging, or anything. On the flip side, I DO intend to do a lot of pushing and popping, and the queue will be changing size quite a bit, so preallocating would be inefficient)

Comment: Maybe you need to step back and think about if there is a better way than pushing thousands of individual pixels one by one into a data structure (if that is indeed what you are doing).

Comment: It's a blob detection algorithm, the idea is that it starts from a point on the blob and traverses outwards to the edge of the blob. I do not believe there is any other (simple) way of doing this. Also, the queue just stores points of interest -- It doesn't actually keep the pixels in the queue, the queue mainly just serves as a way of keeping track of where it is. Similar to many pathfinding algorithms

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Use:

```
Queue<Object> queue = new LinkedList<>();
```

You can use `.offer(E e)` to append an element to the end of the queue and `.poll()` to dequeue and retrieve the head (first element) of the queue.

Java defined the interface `Queue`, the [LinkedList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) provided an implementation.

It also maintains references to the Head and Tail elements, which you can get by `.getFirst()` and `.getLast()` respectively.

*credit to @Snicolas for suggesting queue interface*

Comment: I would prefer using the `Queue` methods implemented by the linkedList : add to enqueue and poll to dequeue.

Comment: My answer to this question talks about that, please see below. It is not recommended to use LinkedList, but to instantiate it as Queue interface... see below.

Answer (score 52):

If you use LinkedList be careful. If you use it like this:

```
LinkedList<String> queue = new LinkedList<String>();
```

then you can violate queue definition, because it is possible to remove other elements than first (there are such methods in LinkedList).

But if you use it like this:

```
Queue<String> queue = new LinkedList<String>();
```

it should be ok,as this is heads-up to users that insertions should occur only at the back and deletions only at the front.

You can overcome defective implementation of the Queue interface by extending the LinkedList class to a PureQueue class that throws UnsupportedOperationException of any of the offending methods. Or you can take approach with aggreagation by creating PureQueue with only one field which is type LinkedList object, list, and the only methods will be a default constructor, a copy constructor, `isEmpty()`, `size()`, `add(E element)`, `remove()`, and `element()`. All those methods should be one-liners, as for example:

```
/**
* Retrieves and removes the head of this queue.
* The worstTime(n) is constant and averageTime(n) is constant.
*
* @return the head of this queue.
* @throws NoSuchElementException if this queue is empty.
*/
public E remove()
{
    return list.removeFirst();
} // method remove()
```

Answer (score 15):

Check out the [Deque](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) interface, which provides for insertions/removals at both ends. LinkedList implements that interface (as mentioned above), but for your use, an ArrayDeque may be better -- you won't incur the cost of constant object allocations for each node. Then again, it may not matter which implementation you use.

Normal polymoprhism goodness comes to play: the beauty of writing against the Deque interface, rather than any specific implementation of it, is that you can very easily switch implementations to test which one performs best. Just change the line with `new` in it, and the rest of the code stays the same.

Answer (score 15):

It's better to use ArrayDeque instead of LinkedList when implementing Stack and Queue in Java. ArrayDeque is likely to be faster than Stack interface (while Stack is thread-safe) when used as a stack, and faster than LinkedList when used as a queue. Have a look at this link [Use ArrayDeque instead of LinkedList or Stack](https://github.com/google/error-prone/issues/257).

Answer (score 2):

If you know the upper bound of possible quantity of items in the queue, circular buffer is faster than LinkedList, as LinkedList creates an object (link) for each item in the queue.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can some up with simple like implementation

```
package DataStructures;

public class Queue<T> {

   private Node<T> root;

   public Queue(T value) {
      root = new Node<T>(value);
   }

   public void enque(T value) {
      Node<T> node = new Node<T>(value);
      node.setNext(root);
      root = node;
   }

   public Node<T> deque() {

      Node<T> node = root;
      Node<T> previous = null;

      while(node.next() != null) {
         previous = node;
         node = node.next();
      }
      node = previous.next();
      previous.setNext(null);
      return node;
   }

   static class Node<T> {

      private T value;
      private Node<T> next;

      public Node (T value) {
         this.value = value;
      }

      public void setValue(T value) {
         this.value = value;
      }

      public T getValue() {
         return value;
      }

      public void setNext(Node<T> next) {
         this.next = next;
      }

      public Node<T> next() {
         return next;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Deque operation takes O(n) time in worst case and a queue data structure should take constant time for insertion and deletion.This is a naive implementation of a queue and please avoid it.

Comment: Why are you returning `Node<T>` instead of `T` in your deque method?

Comment: It'd be nice if this implemented the `java.util.Queue` interface.

Comment: Just a small correction, the dequeue method should return a 'T'. A Node is the internal implementation of the Queue and should not be available outside the Queue implementation.

Answer (score 1):

However, if you still want to use the recursive algorithm, you can change it to be ["tail-recursive"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) which probably is optimized in the JVM to avoid stack overflows.

Comment: Yes you are right as tail recursions will overcome the stack overflow errors. I know that Tail Recursion is supported in a language like Scala itself to do optimizations. However I doubt whether the Tail recursion is not supported in Java. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: The JVM could support something much more general with special opcodes, and the Java compiler could implement it directly under pretty restricted conditions. There's a wishlist item, but it never made it to actual implementation in the past, though it may make it in the future. -- Also, you shouldn't recommend relying on an optimization that "probably exists", particularly not if the presence/absence of the optimization will make the program work resp. crash.

Answer (score 1):

O(1) access to first and last nodes.

```
class Queue {

    private Node head;
    private Node end;

    public void enqueue(Integer data){

        Node node = new Node(data);
        if(this.end == null){
            this.head = node;
            this.end = this.head;
        }
        else {
            this.end.setNext(node);
            this.end = node;
        }
    }

    public void dequeue (){

        if (head == end){
            end = null;
        }

        head = this.head.getNext();
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return head.getData().toString();
    }

    public String deepToString() {

        StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();
        res.append(head.getData());

        Node cur = head;
        while (null != (cur = cur.getNext())){
            res.append(" ");
            res.append(cur.getData());

        }
        return res.toString();
    }
}

class Node {

    private Node next;
    private Integer data;


    Node(Integer i){
        data = i;
    }

    public Integer getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public Node getNext() {
        return next;
    }

    public void setNext(Node next) {
        this.next = next;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the **Queue** Implementation with **Iterator** and **Iterable** interface

Queue Size will increase as It gets full

**Queue Interface**

```
package com.practice.ds.queue;

import com.practice.ds.queue.exception.QueueException;

public interface QueueInterface<T> {

    public boolean empty();

    public void enqueue(T item);

    public void dequeue() throws QueueException;

    public T front() throws QueueException;

    public void clear();
}
```

**Custom Exception Class**

```
package com.practice.ds.queue.exception;

public class QueueException extends Exception {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -884127093599336807L;

    public QueueException() {
        super();
    }

    public QueueException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }

    public QueueException(Throwable e) {
        super(e);
    }

    public QueueException(String message, Throwable e) {
        super(message, e);
    }
}
```

**Implementation of Queue**

```
package com.practice.ds.queue;

import java.util.Iterator;

import com.practice.ds.queue.exception.QueueException;

public class Queue<T> implements QueueInterface<T>, Iterable<T> {

    private static final int DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 10;
    private int current = 0;
    private int rear = 0;
    private T[] queueArray = null;
    private int capacity = 0;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public Queue() {
        capacity = DEFAULT_CAPACITY;
        queueArray = (T[]) new Object[DEFAULT_CAPACITY];
        rear = 0;
        current = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean empty() {
        return capacity == current;
    }

    @Override
    public void enqueue(T item) {
        if(full())
            ensureCapacity();
        queueArray[current] = item;
        current++;
    }

    @Override
    public void dequeue() throws QueueException {
        T dequeuedItem = front();
        rear++;
        System.out.println("Dequed Item is " + dequeuedItem);
    }

    @Override
    public T front() throws QueueException {
        return queueArray[rear];
    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {
        for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++)
            queueArray[i] = null;
        current = 0;
        rear = 0;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private void ensureCapacity() {
        if (rear != 0) {
            copyElements(queueArray);
        } else {
            capacity *= 2;
            T[] tempQueueArray = (T[]) new Object[capacity];
            copyElements(tempQueueArray);
        }
        current -= rear;
        rear = 0;
    }

    private void copyElements(T[] array) {
        for (int i = rear; i < current; i++)
            array[i - rear] = queueArray[i];
        queueArray = array;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        return new QueueItearator<T>();
    }

    public boolean full() {
        return current == capacity;
    }

    private class QueueItearator<T> implements Iterator<T> {

        private int index = rear;

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return index < current;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        public T next() {
            return (T) queueArray[index++];
        }
    }

}
```